# Проблема с Tomcat Unknown version of Tomcat was specified

Tags: apache, eclipse, tomcat

Установил на Ubuntu Tomcat, положил его а в директорию `/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.3`

Создаю подключение в Eclipse и получаю вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу нажать 'finish'

Знаю, подобные вопросы есть но ни одно решение не помогло..

Comment: А права у вашего пользователя есть на запуск исполняемых файлов в этой директории? Зачем вам в `/usr/local`, киньте где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге?

Comment: @enzo Перенес в home, результат тот же

Comment: Либо не то скачали, либо не в тот каталог Eclipse показываете, либо прав нет.